# RealmSwift : MoveRow At IndexPath went wrong

Tags: swift, realm, tableview, reorderable-list

I have a list of AccountType which contain Account models and my TableView is listing them. like below.

However, I could not moveRowAtIndexPath using realm and even if I did moved the row in indexPath, indexPath data does not change at all.

Issue 1 :
If I move `(AccountType A account 1)` to `(AccountType A account 2)` position. `account 1` will now show the data of `account 2`

Issue 2 : tableView will back to original list if I reopen it even if I did saved using realm.write in moveRow At IndexPath.

Issue 3 : `Account(indexPath.row)` are meant to be within `AccountType(indexPath.Section)` I can move it to any section.

```
 var listAccountType  = List<AccountType>()
    var listAccount = List<Account>()
```

```
AccountType A //indexPath.section
- account 1 //indexPath.row
- account 2 //indexPath.row
- account 3 //indexPath.row

AccountType B //indexPath.section
- account 1
- account 2
- account 3

AccountType C //indexPath.section
- account 1
- account 2
- account 3
```

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
         override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        try! realm.write {
            let sourceObject = listAccountType[sourceIndexPath.section].ofAccount[sourceIndexPath.row]
              let destinationObject = listAccountType[sourceIndexPath.section].ofAccount[sourceIndexPath.row]

            let destinationObjectOrder = destinationObject

              if sourceIndexPath.row < destinationIndexPath.row {
              for index in sourceIndexPath.row...destinationIndexPath.row {
                let object = listAccount[index]
                object -= 1
              }
              } else {
              for index in (destinationIndexPath.row..<sourceIndexPath.row).reversed() {
              let object = listAccount[index]
                object += 1
              }
              }
              sourceObject.direction = destinationObjectOrder
              }

             ///Require int variable in  Account() for indexing : create @objc dynamic var accIndex : Int = 0 first
             try! listAccount.realm?.write {
                 listAccount.move(from: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
                 self.tableView.moveRow(at: sourceIndexPath, to: destinationIndexPath)
             }
             print("moved Account")
       }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an Realm observer on your dataSource data?

Comment: Nope, I did not have any realm observer on datasource data yet, just learnt realm 2 weeks ago and still not familiar with it. Mind provide some guides ?

Comment: @JunyongYap It would help if you posted the full definitions of your model objects. It's also unclear what you are trying to do with your for loops and even more unclear what listAccount is and how you're performing arithmetic with its elements (object += 1). However, there are a few noticeable problems. First, you are using `sourceIndexPath` as in index when you instantiate `destinationObject`. I would think you'd want to use destinationIndexPath. As it stands, destinationObject and sourceObject reference the same object. Second, you don't need to call `tableView.moveRow(at:to:)`